# what is the valid format for a tiff image in python

Tags: image, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

How do I write a valid tiff image in python with my own data for the tiff file?

I've tried doing a few things using PIL and it's not a valid image.

If you could answer with some sample code of making a tiff image then editing the data using PIL that would be more than enough and go a long way in moving my program along

Comment: I think [tifffile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile) might be the package you are looking for. I have never used it myself, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: It uses numpy don't have numpy and would prefer to limit module usage looking to only use PIL preferrably. I'd taken a look at tifffile and tiffany earlier today

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#tiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you required to exactly use PIL? Otherwise, have you tried using it's open source clone called Pillow? Refer to https://python-pillow.github.io/

Pillow seems to be able to directly save image data in tiff file format.

Try something like:

```
img = Image()
# any editing of 'img'
img.save( 'mytiff.tif' )
```

Otherwise, you should clarify your needs or problems in depth.